# Cannot detect Xbox controller movements in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, xbox-one

I've been using pygame as a means of creating a game, and I would like to incorporate controller gameplay into the game. I have been using a new Xbox One controller on pygame and have been able to detect the controller in pygame and such, however none of the pygame.get_event functions ever work and always return their default values even when I move the controller's joysticks around and press the buttons as well.

I have tried pygame.event.pump() to no avail. Here is my code:

```
    xboxController = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    xboxController.init()
    print(xboxController.get_name())
    print("Axes", (xboxController.get_numaxes()))
    print("Balls", xboxController.get_numballs())
    print("Buttons", xboxController.get_numbuttons())
    print("Hats", xboxController.get_numhats())
    if xboxController.get_init() == True: print("Initialized properly")

    while not found:
        trial += 1
        print(trial)
        pygame.event.pump()
        for a in range(0, xboxController.get_numaxes()):
            if round(xboxController.get_axis(a)*100) != 0:
                print(xboxController.get_axis(a))
        for b in range(0, xboxController.get_numballs()):
            if xboxController.get_ball(b) != 0: 
                print(xboxController.get_ball(b))
        for c in range(0, xboxController.get_numbuttons()):
            if xboxController.get_button(c) != False: 
                print(xboxController.get_axis(button(c)))
        for d in range(0, xboxController.get_numhats()):
            if xboxController.get_hat(d) != (0, 0): 
                print(xboxController.get_hat(d))
```

The first part where I print out all of the properties of the controller works fine, it just never seems to know when the controller's joysticks are being moved.

Answer (score 1):

I am also making a game with an Xbox controller, and experienced a very similar problem. My problem was fixed simply by using `pygame.event.get()` instead of `pygame.event.pump()`. You don't even need to do anything with the results, just getting the events seems to make pygame update the joystick positions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I replaced my pygame.event.pum() with pygame.event.get() and it still does not seem to be working.

Comment: hmm, strange. does it detect button presses successfully?

Comment: Nothing gets detected at all. I built the program above to test the functionality of everything and nothing seems to work. It all returns their default values.

Comment: does `print(xboxController.get_numaxes())` give a correct number?

Comment: Yeah. Everything above the while loop works with the controller, it's just detecting its movements that does not work.

Comment: I ran this line by line, the for loops run for the amount of time that they should be running.

Comment: try running without the `if round ...` to see if it is causing the problem.

Comment: I just keep getting a bunch of zeros and falses.

Comment: are you using the latest version of pygame? it could be that the version you're using doesn't support Xbox One for some reason

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the latest version of pygame now.

Comment: well, I do see one mistake, even though it's not your problem. In the buttons loop, you are printing `get_axis()`.